# Codemirror - Hints/Autocomplete with separator

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Is there an easy way to add a separator in the hints/autocomplete addon ?

The separator would make the suggestion box look like:

```
f1
f2
f3
---
var1
var2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can attach `className` properties to completions that will be given to the completion's DOM element. If you style some completions with a `border-bottom`, that'll look like a separator.